# Deserialize JSON array php

Tags: php, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON array returned from mssql:

```
[  
   {  
      "Cust_id":38,
      "Contact_id":159,
      "Installer":true,
      "Supervisor":true,
      "Admin":true,
      "Token":"26754782238745DD4B7FEFA375FD5160"
   }
]
```

The PHP code I'm using:

```
$user_data = json_decode($response['body'], true); 
//$response['body'] being the json returned from mssql
```

But, if I try to print `$user_data[0]`, I get the output:

```
381591113C93986662D8AABBCC420C196F821D7E
```

Which is the value of the JSON, but concatenated.

I have tried several combinations to no avail, all the other queries return without the array wrapper and deserialize fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem https://3v4l.org/UqAMb

Comment: it should work. I tried like this `$string = '[{"Cust_id":38,"Contact_id":159,"Installer":true,"Supervisor":true,"Admin":true,"Token":"26754782238745DD4B7FEFA375FD5160"}]';
$user_data = json_decode($string, true); 
print_r($user_data[0]);
` it works

Comment: did you use array_values() kind of thing in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to deserialize array provided by you and print value @ 0th index of output.
The result seems fine.

```
$arrayFromSql = '[  
   {  
      "Cust_id":38,
      "Contact_id":159,
      "Installer":true,
      "Supervisor":true,
      "Admin":true,
      "Token":"26754782238745DD4B7FEFA375FD5160"
   }
]'; 
        $decodedArray = json_decode($arrayFromSql, true); 
        var_dump($decodedArray[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(6){  
   [  
      "Cust_id"
   ]   => int(38)   [  
      "Contact_id"
   ]   => int(159)   [  
      "Installer"
   ]   => bool(true)   [  
      "Supervisor"
   ]   => bool(true)   [  
      "Admin"
   ]   => bool(true)   [  
      "Token"
   ]   => string(32) "26754782238745DD4B7FEFA375FD5160"
}bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works.

```
$body='[  
   {  
      "Cust_id":38,
      "Contact_id":159,
      "Installer":true,
      "Supervisor":true,
      "Admin":true,
      "Token":"26754782238745DD4B7FEFA375FD5160"
   }
]'; 

    $user_data = json_decode($body, true);  
    print_r($user_data[0]);
```

Output

```
Array ([  
   Cust_id
]=> 38[  
   Contact_id
]=> 159[  
   Installer
]=> 1[  
   Supervisor
]=> 1[  
   Admin
]=> 1[  
   Token
]=> 26754782238745DD4B7FEFA375FD5160 )
```